# List index out of range (python jupyter)

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
films = { 'title': titles, 'rank': ranks, 'synopsis': synopses, 'cluster': clusters, 'genre': genres }

#frame = pd.DataFrame(films[frame] for frame in films.keys())
frame = pd.DataFrame(films,columns = ['rank', 'title', 'cluster', 'genre'])
dups_shape = frame.pivot_table(index=['cluster'], aggfunc='size')
print (dups_shape)

items = { 'title': titles, 'Synopses': synopses}

frame = pd.DataFrame(items, index = [clusters] , columns = [ 'title','cluster'])


print("Top terms per cluster:")

# sort cluster centers by proximity to centroid
order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]

for i in range(num_clusters):
    print("Cluster %d words:" % i, end='')

    for ind in order_centroids[i, :6]:  # replace 6 with n words per cluster
        print(' %s' % vocab_frame.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0], end=',')


    print()
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. because I copied this code and adjust it according to my project.

EDIT: Full traceback provided by OP in comments

```
    Top terms per cluster:
    Cluster 0 words:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IndexError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-40-2088a7881446> in <module>
    13
    14 for ind in order_centroids[i, :6]: # replace 6 with n words per cluster 
--->15 print(' %s' % vocab_frame.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0], end=',')
    16
    17 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? I mean, the whole error message? It may give us more perspective about the real issue

Comment: please add the error also, so its easy to understand

Comment: The most valuable thing to look at is which line is throwing the error.

Comment: Top terms per cluster:
Cluster 0 words:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-2088a7881446> in <module>
     13 
     14     for ind in order_centroids[i, :6]:  # replace 6 with n words per cluster
---> 15         print(' %s' % vocab_frame.loc[terms[ind].split(' ')].values.tolist()[0][0], end=',')
     16 
     17 

IndexError: list index out of range
Here's the error message

Comment: About tolist method: `These are each a scalar type, which is a Python scalar (for str, int, float) or a pandas scalar (for Timestamp/Timedelta/Interval/Period)` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html Didn't you mean index [0] instead of [0][0]?

Comment: i change the index [0][0] to [0] but it still display the same error