# Labelling texts using sklearn: Index Error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am trying to assign labels to texts using clusters. To do this, I am following the steps at this link:

https://towardsdatascience.com/applying-machine-learning-to-classify-an-unsupervised-text-document-e7bb6265f52

However, after selecting all the terms in the cluster (I have three clusters) as follows:

```
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
terms
```

where `len(terms)=2009`,I get the following error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

when I run this code:

```
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind], end='') # the error comes from here
        print()
```

where `true_k=3`. 
This link: [List index out of range (python jupyter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58118257/list-index-out-of-range-python-jupyter) uunfortunately does not have any relevant information to fix this issue. 
It seems that cluster 1 may cause the problem and also the number of words [:10].

Do you know why it happens and how to fix it?
If you need more code and info, I will be happy to update the question.

**Sample**

*Doc*

```
“12 minutes ago - There was a meeting...”
“2 hours ago - Apologies for being...”
“1 day ago - It is a sunny day in London...”
```

...
I have 130 rows.

**Code**

```
import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

def preprocessing(line):
    line = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", line.lower())
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    words_lemm = [WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(w) for w in words if w not in stop_words]
    return words_lemm

true_k=3
vect =TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=preprocessing)
vectorized_text=vect.fit_transform(df['Doc'])
kmeans =KMeans(n_clusters=true_k).fit(vectorized_text)

# Predict cluster 
cl=kmeans.predict(vectorized_text)
df['Predicted Cluster']=pd.Series(cl, index=df.index)

# Transform to plot
pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer())])
X = pipeline.fit_transform(df['Doc']).todense()
pca = PCA(n_components=3).fit(X)
data2D = pca.transform(X)
kmeans.fit(X)
centers2D = pca.transform(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
```

## Top terms per cluster

```
order_centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vect.get_feature_names()

for i in range(1):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print('%s' % terms[ind])
    print()
```

Comment: More code that forms a complete sub-example would be nice. In short, something is either wrong in the order_centroids[i, :10] call or the terms[ind] call, but it's not immediately obvious to me which one.

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know if you need further rows. @AndrewH